# json expand in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

Any suggestion how to pull from this JSON file to powershell the results mention below thanks in advance 
JSON FILE 

`{
  "meta": {
    "effective_params": {
      "data_set": "Website",
      "base_currencies": [
        "USD"
      ]
    },
    "endpoint": "spot",
    "request_time": "2018-06-20T18:06:59+00:00",
    "skipped_currency_pairs": []`
},
"quotes":`[
   {
      "base_currency": "USD",
      "quote_currency": "AUD",
      "bid": "1.35494",
      "ask": "1.35516",
      "midpoint": "1.35505"
    },
    {
      "base_currency": "USD",
      "quote_currency": "BRL",
      "bid": "3.75455",
      "ask": "3.75705",
      "midpoint": "3.75580"
  ]
}`

I trying to get this RESULT :      
`request_time :2018-06-20T18:06:59+00:00` 
`base_currency : USD`
 `quote_currency : ZAR`
 `bid : 13.6187` 
`ask : 13.6276`
 `midpoint : 13.6232`

Comment: You have two quotes objects, how do you know which one contains the values you want?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

First, your JSON object is invalid. You are missing } after the second midpoint.

```
$json = Get-content -raw -path C:\path\to\file.json 
$obj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json

##get all quote info
$obj.quotes 

##get one set
write-host request_time: $obj.meta.request_time
write-host base_currency: $obj.quotes[0].base_currency
write-host quote_currency: $obj.quotes[0].quote_currency
write-host bid: $obj.quotes[0].bid
write-host ask: $obj.quotes[0].ask
write-host midpoint: $obj.quotes[0].ask

##loop through

$rTime = $obj.meta.request_time;

ForEach($i in $obj.quotes){
write-host request_time: $rTime
write-host base_currency: $i.base_currency
write-host quote_currency: $i.quote_currency
write-host bid: $i.bid
write-host ask: $i.ask
write-host midpoint: $i.ask
""
}
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly get the results "into powershell", more it simply prints them to a console in a form that is less usable than original. I would suggest creating an array of psobjects instead.

Comment: "into powershell" is ambiguous. Could be to show it, or to save it as a variable. Yes, we could create a new object for him.. but lets just lead the horse to water and see if he can learn to drink.

Comment: In general using bad conventions such as write-host is more like leading a horse into a pit of phosphorus gas

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$json = @"
  {
  "meta": {
    "effective_params": {
      "data_set": "Website",
      "base_currencies": [
        "USD"
      ]
    },
    "endpoint": "spot",
    "request_time": "2018-06-20T18:06:59+00:00",
    "skipped_currency_pairs": []
},
"quotes":[
   {
      "base_currency": "USD",
      "quote_currency": "AUD",
      "bid": "1.35494",
      "ask": "1.35516",
      "midpoint": "1.35505"
    },
    {
      "base_currency": "USD",
      "quote_currency": "BRL",
      "bid": "3.75455",
      "ask": "3.75705",
      "midpoint": "3.75580"
  }
  ]
}
"@

$obj = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$result = foreach( $quote in $obj.quotes ) {

    "request_time :      $($obj.meta.request_time)"
    "base_currency :     $($quote.base_currency)"
    "quote_currency :    $($quote.quote_currency)"
    "bid :               $($quote.bid)"
    "ask :               $($quote.ask)"
    "midpoint :          $($quote.midpoint)"
} 

$result
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is coming from some other PowerShell code that is retrieving the JSON object, and (again) assuming you are just trying to display the JSON on screen, it is quite simple really.

Wrap the code that retrieves the JSON result, pipe to `ConvertFrom-Json`, and then access the `quotes` member collection.

For example:

```
(('<code that returns a JSON object>') | ConvertFrom-Json).quotes
```

And a tad bit more realistically...

```
((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "HTTPS://Website.domain/API?param=value").Content | ConvertFrom-Json).quotes
```

Or if you simpy want to import raw JSON in PowerShell and see the quote objects in native PowerShell format:

```
((Get-content -Path C:\path\to\file.json) | ConvertFrom-Json).quotes
```

Or to store the JSON object and use later:

```
$JSON = (Get-content -Path C:\path\to\file.json) | ConvertFrom-Json
$JSON.quotes
```